# How can I create this custom pop-up message in Android activity?

Tags: android, dialog, popup

I am tasked with creating this kind of pop-up message for an app. I attached an image bellow with the design,

[image: Pop-Up Custom Design]

Note that the pop-up is placed right bellow a certain ImageButton to indicate something about it. The pop-up must also contain an ImageView, a TextView and two Buttons.

I know that the Alert Dialog native for Android opens a Dialog Popup at the center of the screen that has a rectangular shape and also makes the background behind it darker. But I want to create something that matches this design exactly and right now I have no idea how.

Can anyone show me how to do this, if necessary, even a library would help. All that matters is that the solution has to work on any Android OS equal or higher than v6.0 (Marshmallow).

Thank You!

Comment: https://android-arsenal.com/tag/30 here's list of dioalogs

Comment: @NavinKumar thnak you, I'll take a look at all of those! :)

Answer (score 1):

Below popup library will help

**https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/2927**

you can inflate your custom View into this library

Comment: Thank you, I think it's good enough. I'll try customizing it so it can match the above design. Cheers!